# How to move limits above and below a letter/text?

Tags: math-mode, amsmath

In LaTeX, is there a way to move the limits above and below an arbitrary letter/text? I know that for certain mathematical operations you can just use the `$\limits$` command for this, such as `$\sum\limits_{i = a}^{b}(i)$` = $\sum\limits_{i = a}^{b}(i)$.

I'm attempting to define some functions over a range in my document, like $\mathbf{U}_{a}^{b}(x)$ and I stylistically I would prefer the limits to appear above and below the $\mathbf{U}$ rather than adjacent to it. I've tried using the `$\limits$` command, but it doesn't appear to be compatible with this use case.

(Sidebar: why is the latex which is not in code blocks above not being rendered properly? They have it on the math stack exchange?)

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Here we don't have MathJax enabled, because we're interested in the output from TeX, not from an approximation that might be misleading.

Comment: As far as the question is concerned, I believe it's a duplicate, but you're served by `\operatorname*{\mathbf{U}}\limits_{a}^{b}` (requires `amsmath`).

Comment: @egreg Thank you! I tried searching around for an answer to this, but I must not have entered in the proper search terms because I couldn't find an answer via googling.